# Max Sample Rate of an Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno

I am using the FFT library from Open Music Labs and I am trying to analyze frequencies up to 40 kHz. Now I don't understand fully but know that my sample rate has to be at least twice as much, but my question is with the example code fft_adc_serial, how can I adjust the sample frequency to 80kHz? Is it even possible to sample at these high frequencies.

Comment: 112 us, 8.9 k samples per second max on an arduino uno. And that is if you do extreme programming.

Comment: Trying to get 80kHz from an Uno will reduce the samples to unusable garbage.

Comment: From the datasheet: "Up to 76.9kSPS (Up to 15kSPS at Maximum Resolution)"

Comment: Nick Gammon has some [ADC tests](https://www.gammon.com.au/adc) that show the accuracy as a function of the prescaler setting. From his data, prescaler = 16 (which gives a sampling rate of 76.9 kS/s) seems still almost accurate, whereas prescaler = 8 (153.8 kS/s) seems to leave only 3 – 5 bits of effective resolution.