# Detecting peak frequency in a microphone's output signal

Tags: arduino-uno, signal-processing

I'm using a simple electrode microphone with an Arduino UNO board with the aim of detecting peak frequencies in the output signal overtime. I set the sampling rate to 1 MHz, but i can't pick up a peak that is above 4000 Hz(I've verified the values with regression but it's only true for the range [200 Hz, 3900 Hz]). So my questions are:

- Is this due to the microphone's sensibility or to the Arduino UNO?
- Someone suggested me an ESP32, but i don't understand what difference it'll make.

CODE:

```
#include "arduinoFFT.h"
float peak = 0;
float val = 0;
#define SAMPLES 128            //SAMPLES-pt FFT. Must be a base 2 number. Max 128 for Arduino Uno.
#define SAMPLING_FREQUENCY 1000000 //Ts = Based on Nyquist, must be 2 times the highest expected frequency.
 
arduinoFFT FFT = arduinoFFT();
 
unsigned int samplingPeriod;
unsigned long microSeconds;
 
double vReal[SAMPLES]; //create vector of size SAMPLES to hold real values
double vImag[SAMPLES]; //create vector of size SAMPLES to hold imaginary values
 
void setup() 
{
    Serial.begin(115200); 
    samplingPeriod = round(1000000*(1.0/SAMPLING_FREQUENCY)); //Period in microseconds
    
}
 
void loop() 
{  
    
    for(int i=0; i<SAMPLES; i++)
    {
        microSeconds = micros();   
        val = analogRead(0);
        vReal[i] = val; 
        vImag[i] = 0; 

       
        while(micros() < (microSeconds + samplingPeriod))
        {
          
        }
    }
 
    
    FFT.Windowing(vReal, SAMPLES, FFT_WIN_TYP_HAMMING, FFT_FORWARD);
    FFT.Compute(vReal, vImag, SAMPLES, FFT_FORWARD);
    FFT.ComplexToMagnitude(vReal, vImag, SAMPLES);

    
    peak = FFT.MajorPeak(vReal, SAMPLES, SAMPLING_FREQUENCY);
    Serial.println((peak-5063)/122.5); 
    Serial.print(";");
```

Comment: i've used the included FFT library, and generated sounds with an app then verified the measured frequencies with the Spectroid app, albeit i had to put the source right at the microphone.

Comment: Related: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/44868/max-sample-rate-of-an-arduino-uno

Comment: I doubt, that you really have an ADC sampling frequency of 1MHz on an Arduino Uno. 4kHz seems to be about aligned with 2x the max sample rate in the first comment of that question (niquist frequency). The ESP32 was surely suggested, because it runs on a way faster clock. Mine is set to 240MHz by default (in contrast to the Unos 16MHz). Please show us your code

Comment: here is my code :

Comment: please check the question

Comment: If you write big integer literals, make sure that they are interpreted as `long`. So write `1000000L` instead of just `1000000`. Then please try again. Also you can use `micros()` to measure the time, that your measurement loop actually needs. That would make sure, that you are not actually slower with sampling than you think.

Comment: So you think there's now way getting around buying another more precise card?

Comment: alright i'll try that. thanks.

Comment: so i tried the long integer type but it's pretty obvious that the UNO's sampling rate doesn't match for the job. Are there any better arduino cards? I'm only interested in the audible brandwith to suggest a device that alerts in dominance of frequencies at high intensities.

Comment: There are only few Arduino boards, which are slower than the Uno. So look at what is available for you and check the clock frequency. Research the max ADC sample rate for those boards. Then you can choose one. The ESP32 is only one possibility.

Comment: Hello sir. The output of my microphone is way too low. When measuring the span(max - min) of my signal(wich i'll use later on), the span is always around 2, and i need to cough really lough, and close to the mic for it to change. Is amplification inevitable? Because my microphonealready had an in-built amplifier?

Comment: You need a voltage between ground and Vcc of your board (5V on the Uno, 3.3V on boards like the ESP32). Fi your microphone module doesn't provide that, then you need further amplication.

Comment: when i coud loud enough the signal peak to peak can reach 2 volts, so i think the amplifier that is built-in is good enough..